# MySQL Abortar insert si se cumple una condicion

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

Estoy empezando a estudiar los triggers y tengo un ejercicio que gira alrededor de partidos de fútbol, equipos, jornadas, etc... y me han encargado que haga un trigger que, además de otras cosas, compruebe si dos equipos ya se han enfrentado dos veces (que es el numero máximo de partidos que pueden jugar uno contra otro en una misma temporada). En caso afirmativo, no debería permitir hacer un insert en el que estén involucrados esos dos equipos.

El trigger, actualmente es mucho más gordo, pero lo simplifico para mostrar solo la parte que debe comprobar esto...

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS BI_InsercionJornada
//
CREATE TRIGGER BI_InsercionJornada BEFORE INSERT ON partidos FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partidos 
        WHERE ((equipoLocal = new.equipoLocal OR equipoVisitante = new.equipoLocal) 
        AND (equipoLocal = new.equipoVisitante OR equipoVisitante = new.equipoVisitante)) < 2) 
        THEN

            bla bla bla...

        ELSE 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error';
        END IF;
    END;
//
```

Aparentemente, y a pesar de que en la tabla "partidos" ya hay dos partidos en los que el Equipo1 y el Equipo2 se han enfrentado, el trigger permite la inserción, y ya llevo un rato mirándolo y no entiendo qué hago mal.

EDITO: Adjunto la declaración de las tablas

```
CREATE TABLE equipos (
    Abreviatura VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Nombre_Equipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    GolesFavor INT(2) NOT NULL,
    GolesContra INT(2) NOT NULL,
    Puntos INT(3) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (Abreviatura)
)ENGINE = INNODB CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE partidos (
    idPartido INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    jornada INT(2) NOT NULL,
    equipoLocal VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    golesLocal INT(2) NOT NULL,
    equipoVisitante VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    golesVisitante INT(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idPartido),
    CONSTRAINT fk_equipoLocal FOREIGN KEY (equipoLocal) REFERENCES equipos(Abreviatura),
    CONSTRAINT fk_equipoVisitante FOREIGN KEY (equipoVisitante) REFERENCES equipos(Abreviatura)
)ENGINE = INNODB CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: Convendría agregues la declaración de tus tablas

Comment: Hecho! Espero que ayude.

Comment: El problema está en la consulta (`SELECT`), evalúe cuidadosamente las condiciones del `WHERE`.